# implementing conv2d in fourier domain using einsum --> ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand 0

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

According to the convolution theorem, convolution operation changes to pointwise multiplication in fourier domain - 
here I have 'fft_x' of shape (batchsize, height, width, in_channels) which is the fft of input data 
and similarly 'fft_kernel' of shape (height, width, in_channels, out_channels) which is fft of the kernel after being padded to image size. To get pointwise multiplication of these in efficient way, I was using einsum in the following way -

```
...
    print(fft_x)
    print(fft_kernel)
    output = 0
    n=int(self.no_of_kernels/2)+1      # n = out_channels here
    for i in range(n):
        output += np.einsum('ijkl,jkl->ijk', fft_x, fft_kernel[i])
    return output 
...
```

It gives the following output -

```
Tensor("input_11:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=complex64)
Tensor("fourier__conv2d_11/transpose:0", shape=(28, 28, 1, 17), dtype=complex64)
...
...
ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand 0
```

Could anyone please explain why this error is arising? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You may be need to convert these `Tensor` objects to regular `ndarray` first.

Comment: But when I run this to get ndarray, `  with tf.Session() as sess:
            fft_x = fft_x.eval()
            fft_kernel = fft_kernel.eval()       `  I get the following error - `InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype complex64 and shape [?,28,28,1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tf.einsum instead of np.einsum, and it worked.